# Good Save/Load Function For Text Incremental Game (C++)

Tags: c++

I am making a incremental game were you earn rubies every 1 second, and you can buy upgrades and such. I am working on a save/load function for it, but not really knowing what I am doing, it has not gotten very far. I was thinking that I could save to a file in the same location as the game and print to it everything that needs to be saved on the same line separated by "@" signs (this is the easy part). It should end up looking like this `@12@13@1@2@5@`, but that really is `@rubies@stone@etc.@`. Then when you want to load it, it reads the file and every time it sees an "@" sign it knows that until the next sign what it reads will be assigned to that variable, then at the next sign it knows that what follows it until the next sign is the next variable. Right now the code I have for the save function is:

```
void save() {
cout << "The game is going to save to wherever the game currently is right now to avoid confusion\n";

try {
    ofstream rubyMineSave;
    rubyMineSave.open("RubyFileSave.txt");
    rubyMineSave << rubies << "@" << endl;
    rubyMineSave << rubiesLocation << "@" << endl;
    rubyMineSave << machineLocation << "@" << endl;
    rubyMineSave << stone << "@" << endl;
    rubyMineSave << openMultiple << "@" << endl;
    rubyMineSave << rubyEarnRate << "@" << endl;
    rubyMineSave << stoneEarnRate << "@" << endl;
    rubyMineSave << rubyMachines << "@" << endl;
    rubyMineSave.close();
    cout << "Saved the game\n";
} catch (...) {
    cout << "Unable to save\n";
}
```

}

And for the load function, I know I need to open the file and read it character by character so I can tell it what to save the variables to. My load function I currently have is:

```
void load() {
string line;
int readLine;

ifstream rubyMineLoad ("RubyFileSave.txt");

if (rubyMineLoad.is_open()) {
    while (getline(rubyMineLoad, line)) {

    }
    rubyMineLoad.close();
} else cout << "Unable to load game, is the save file in the same directory as the game is, and is it called \"RubyFileSave.txt\"\n";
```

}

Please help me, I don`t know how to do this.

Comment: search for "serialization"

Comment: Certainly your game state is stored in memory somehow. Serialize these data structures to a file.